# What am I doing wrong in binding to a class?

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I have a class named PlatypusInfo.

I call a method that returns an instance of that class:

```
PlatypusInfo pi;
. . .
pi = MammalData.PopulateplatypusData(oracleConnectionMainForm, textBoxPlatypusID.Text);
. . .
public static PlatypusInfo PopulateplatypusData(OracleConnection oc, String platypusID) {

    int platypusABCID = getABCIDForDuckBillID(oc, platypusID);
    platypusInfo pi = new platypusInfo();
```

...but get this err msg: *"System.ArgumentException was unhandled
  Message=Cannot bind to the property or column platypusName on the DataSource.
Parameter name: dataMember
  Source=System.Windows.Forms
  ParamName=dataMember"*

...on this line of code:

```
textBoxPlatypusID.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", pi, "platypusName"));
```

I'm thinking that with my code, the platypusName member of the PlatypusInfo class (the instance of which is "pi") should be assigned to textBoxPlatypusID's Text property.

So am I understanding this incorrectly, am I going about it wrong, or both?

Comment: Does the class PlatypusInfo have a public property named 'platypusName' of type string?

Comment: Can you post the code for `PlatypusInfo`

Comment: @John: Not exactly a property:

public class PlatypusInfo {

  public String PlatypusName;

Comment: @John: I don't know how literally you meant "property"

Comment: @ClayShannon - You look to be binding to "platypusName" but you said your property is named "PlatypusName"... Just something to watch out for - the bindings will be case-sensitive.

Comment: @ClayShannon: Change it to a property, and make sure the case matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to change it from a field to a property and add the implementation of the [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229614.aspx) interface.  So something like this:

```
public class PlatypusInfo : INotifyPropertyChanged
{         
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private String _PlatypusName;

    public String PlatypusName 
    { 
       get
       {
          return _PlatypusName;
       }
       set 
       {
          _PlatypusName = value;
          NotifyPropertyChanged("PlatypusName");
       }
    }

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
       PropertyChangedEventHandler property_changed = PropertyChanged;
       if (property_changed != null)
       {
          property_changed(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
       }
    }
}
```

Then the databinding would look like this:

```
textBoxPlatypusID.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", pi, "PlatypusName"));
```

assuming `pi` is a `PlatypusInfo` object.

Answer (score 0):

Does the class PlatypusInfo implements the interface INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: When you using data bind you must implement INotifyPropertyChanged, and for collections you need to use ObservableCollection

Comment: You only have to implement these interfaces if you want your UI to update when the backing data changes. The binding will work regardless.